# Numbers as ### in .CSV

Tags: python, parsing

I'm having problem with parser on Windows(!), on Linux everything is working good.

In my .CSV file I have some numbers displayed as "######", ofc only on windows. If you need to see code -> [My github](https://github.com/gpskwlkr/coinmarketcap-parser-py)

[Screen of the following problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBZTi.jpg)

Comment: widen your columns in Excel?

Comment: problem should be in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could simply be that the cell in Excel is too small to display the value. Have you tried dragging the separator to make it bigger (or double clicking on the separator to make it as wide as necessary)?

Comment: Okay, i've done this so problem is solved partly, can i do this from code somehow ?

Comment: @GiorgiAnakidze You can't because it is a .csv file and this has no style options, with xls/x you can.

Comment: @CraigvanTonder So, what if i switch from .csv to xlsx ?

Comment: @GiorgiAnakidze then check the documentation of whichever library you use to create the file in python, steps to take would varying depending on what you're using and if it has support for styling (I am a python noob so can't help there but in PHP it works like that and should be the same).

Comment: @GiorgiAnakidze You're going to have to use a different library to create `.xlsx` files, as the `csv` module is only capable of creating CSV files.